# FileReader can't find file

Tags: java

For some reason `FileReader` cannot find the file I specified `"read1.json"`. I tried numerous things, changing the name to changing locations but it has nothing to do with the file itself. I'm wondering why it can't find the file.

> Error:(13, 35) java: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
>
> Error:(13, 34) java: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

```
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.URLReader;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

import java.io.FileReader;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Home\\Documents\\read1.json"));

    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    System.out.println(jsonObject);
  }
}
```

Comment: does the file read1.json exist at that path ?

Comment: `FileReader cannot find the file I specified "read1.json"` - No. this is not what the compiler is telling you. The compiler is telling you that you need to handle `FileNotFoundException` if you want to compile the program.

Comment: If you add a try-catch block to this code, and debug when exception caught, what does the exception say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FileReader cannot find the file I specified "read1.json"

No. This is not what the compiler is telling you. The compiler is telling you that you need to handle both `FileNotFoundException` and `IOException` if you want to compile the program.

Use a try-catch block:

```
try {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Home\\Documents\\read1.json"));

    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    System.out.println(jsonObject);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // handle file not found
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle ioexception
}
```

Or add a `throws` clause (bad design in this specific case):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Home\\Documents\\read1.json"));

    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    System.out.println(jsonObject);

}
```

Comment: May I ask why I'd need to use a try catch block? And I have tried your code, it gives me another error: Error:(16, 38) java: unreported exception org.json.simple.parser.ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: @Vitalynx Same thing for the `ParseException`, you need a catch block for it. For questions about exceptions, see the [official guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html)

Answer (score 0):

u need to use try-catch block to handle FileNotFound exception as it is checked exception. and it must be checked at compile time. Compiler throws this error because this can be the probable exception at runtime so it suggest you to handle it before it actually occurs.

Comment: Compiler doesn't throw it, Compiler checks if it is handled. Exceptions get thrown at runtime, not at compile time

Comment: I mean to say this error message compiler will give :
Error:(13, 35) java: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

not exception I was talking about this error message.

Comment: Yeah, it is a compile-time error, not a thrown exception